# Adding data from PostgreSQL to Query Layer of ArcGIS for Desktop warns that given coordinate references are incompatible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, coordinate-system, srid, query-layer

When adding data from PostgreSQL in a Query Layer I get the warning:

> The given coordinate references are incompatible

I have added many other layers with the same properties no problems, but I have 3 problem layers kicking up this error (Of course it's the 3 most important layers that I want). They all have the same SRID. The only thing I have found from research is the 'high precision low precision' problem, but I have no idea which precision they are or how to find that out. It won't let me proceed to the advanced options either.

I have little to no knowledge of PostgreSQL so please explain in real simple terms.

Below is a sample of the data:

[image]

There are no NULL entries, the SRID seems to be the same from what I can see.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: This is in ArcGIS, no? You might want to add that tag to your question. I know nothing about ArcGIS, but you can try running [updategeometrysrid](http://postgis.org/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html) in postgres to ensure that the meta data table, geometry columns, really does have the same srid for all 3 tables.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, thanks. (Added to my tags as well, bit new to the forum)

Comment: No worries. It just helps to get the right eyes on your question, as a lot of people filter by tag. If you have an ArcGIS question, you don't want only open source guys like me being the only ones to see it :D

Comment: Would you be able to also include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using and exact example values that you are feeding into the Query Layer when it works and when it does not, please?

Comment: Its ArcGIS 10.2 but specifically a version developed by Leica. The tables we're loading in are very big so hard to give you exact example values. The tables that don't work however, are very similar to other tables that do work. I will find some geometry from a table that does and does not work though as I guess that could be the problem?

Comment: To avoid the need to try and ask a duplicate question like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123360/postgresql-query-layer-wont-load-into-arcgis-desktop-10-how-can-i-find-the-pro would you be able to focus your efforts on editing this question to make it as clear and comprehensive as you can, please?  Before any answers have been offered is the ideal time to overhaul it to address any clarifications that have been sought via comments.

Comment: There is no answer here. I have more information now but as it was asked so long ago its not as likely to be seen any more. There are no replys to the last comment I posted so I don't really know what to do?!?!

Comment: Every time you edit your question it returns to the Active list so refreshing it whenever new clarifications are sought or you have new information or even just a better way of wording it helps it keep being seen and in an improved state each time.  Comments are not read as often as questions so you need to incorporate anything important into the latter.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the duplicate. Thanks for the advise. Now just need some help getting these postgresql layers in.